# How to update from 10.10

Tags: updates, 10.10

PLEASE HELP! I totally know nothing of this type of things.  My uncle gave it to me, and my family doesn't even know what to do with this.  I've tried upgrading, but it will not!  What steps do I need to do, and could you explain in thorough steps? Thank you for reading this and I appreciate your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Seeing that you are rather inexperienced I advise you to back up data and install the newer system (Ubuntu 14.04) from scrath.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: I think the best approach here is a full re-installation.

---

The upgrade path from 10.10 to a more recent release, 14.04 (Long Term Support) or 15.10 (latest), if even still possible, would go as follows:

10.10 → 11.04 → 11.10 → 12.04 LTS → **14.04 LTS** ( → 14.10 → 15.04 → **15.10** (latest release))

So as you can see, you would have to perform 4 subsequent release upgrades to get to the latest LTS release, and another 3 more to get to the latest release. In each of these upgrade processes, something could break. (And I'm currently ignoring the fact that this will take a long time.)

Also, you may run into performance issues. Ubuntu 10.10 is the last release to ship with the GNOME 2 desktop by default, since 11.04 Canonical shipped Ubuntu with its new Unity desktop, which is a hell lot more demanding on memory and CPU, although I don't know whether it will actually install Unity during a release-upgrade.

So a full reinstallation would be the way to go, if you want to keep using Ubuntu. An explanation on how this is done would be way to exhaustive for this answer, but you can find a very detailed guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation).

As already mentioned, the default Unity desktop may be too demanding for older hardware, but you are free to try ;) You can even boot Ubuntu directly from a DVD or USB, as described in the Installation guide. If it doesn't work well, you may want to have a look at Ubuntu flavors with more lightweight desktops, such as [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) (with Xfce) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) (with LXDE).

Answer (score -1):

Goto "Search your computer and online resources" And search Software Updater and from there you can upgrade to the newest version of ubuntu